# Is it possible to copy a changeset to another workspace without delivering it first?

Tags: version-control, rational-team-concert

I have two workspaces created from the same stream, which share some of the local changes but not others. I would like to copy some of the changes from one workspace to the other.

Normally this is done by delivering a changeset to the stream, at which point all workspaces which track that stream as incoming will see it. However, I'm not ready yet to share the change with the whole team, I'd like to perform this operation in a way that affects my workspaces only. I also don't have permissions to create my own stream.

Is it possible to make a copy of a changeset in another workspace without carrying over the changes manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can change [the flow target](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_scm_eclipse_add_target.html) of your current repository workspace, and add not a stream, but *another* repo workspace.

That way, you deliver to a workspace, not a stream.

That is why I always recommend a repo workspace visibility should be set to scoped, not "private".

If it is private and your important development has been checked in but not delivered, and you are not available (for instance, on holiday), nobody else in your team would be able to fetch your changes from your repo workspace, because of its visibility.

---

If the outgoing change sets are too large (meaning you cannot deliver the one changeset you want without including others), then you can try plan B:
"[**Creating and applying a Jazz source control patch**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9N7T_1.0.0/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_scm_patch.html)".

You can then, in a separate Eclipse instance, apply that patch to a separate repository workspace, [as described in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/76768/choose-which-workspace-to-apply-patch-to).